# What toplevel directives does utop support?

Tags: ocaml, utop

I can't find any documentation on what toplevel directives I can use in utop. All I could find is [this list](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec256) of directives supported by the default ocaml toplevel, but that list doesn't seem to be complete for utop and is missing things like `#typeof`, which I know works in utop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the only one, that isn't documented. The other ones start with `#utop` or are documented by `#utop_help`.
(The `utop_prompt_*` directives should be self-explaining)

You can list all registered directives with:

```
Hashtbl.iter (fun k _v -> print_endline k) Toploop.directive_table
```

Third party libraries can also add, remove, or replace macros.

Comment: Since `utop` v2.0.0 (2016-05-26), [`#utop_help` mentions `#help`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop/blob/4a97c4c2e96b0abdd9776598f195d23f2139a2e8/CHANGES.md?plain=1#L218) with description "list all directives" so I think `#help` is another option.